# Como converter JSON para array para gráfico de coluna no google charts?

Tags: javascript, json, google-charts

Tenho um `JSON` no seguinte formato:

```
[
  {
    "Pais": "Qatar",
    "Valor": 683900
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Luxembourg",
    "Valor": 519360
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Iceland",
    "Valor": 476710
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Bahrain",
    "Valor": 442990
  },
  {
    "Pais": "United States",
    "Valor": 415570
  }
]
```

Quero usar esse `JSON` para popular os dados do gráfico como no exemplo abaixo, mas como posso converter ele para array e utilizar o `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` para carregar os dados?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
 var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Nome', 'Valor'],
    ["Qatar", 683900],
  ["Luxembourg", 519360],
  ["Iceland", 476710],
  ["Bahrain", 442990],
  ["United States", 415570]
 ]);

 var options = {
  width: 800,
  legend: { position: 'none' },
  chart: {
   title: 'Top 5',
   subtitle: 'Uso de energia por país'
  },
  axes: {
   x: {
    0: { side: 'top' } // Top x-axis.
   }
  },
  bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
 };

 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
 // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
 chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[FIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/Wurthmann/k10pzu5e/6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `map` para percorrer o array, passando uma função que recebe o valor dos índices e retorna o novo valor

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Pais": "Qatar",
    "Valor": 683900
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Luxembourg",
    "Valor": 519360
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Iceland",
    "Valor": 476710
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Bahrain",
    "Valor": 442990
  },
  {
    "Pais": "United States",
    "Valor": 415570
  }
];

const dataAsArray = [
  data.map(value => value.Pais),
  data.map(value => value.Valor)
];

console.log(dataAsArray);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas o formato não ficou correto. Consegui da forma que postei na minha resposta.

Comment: Editei a resposta achei que aquele era o formato que queria

Comment: Boa, ficou exatamente com o mesmo formato do que eu fiz mas com um código mais elegante! +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

Converti utilizando `arrays.map` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Pais": "Qatar",
    "Valor": 683900
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Luxembourg",
    "Valor": 519360
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Iceland",
    "Valor": 476710
  },
  {
    "Pais": "Bahrain",
    "Valor": 442990
  },
  {
    "Pais": "United States",
    "Valor": 415570
  }
];

var arrays = ['Pais', 'Valor'];
arrays = arrays.map(function (campo) {
 var novoConteudo = data.map(function (objeto) {
  return objeto[campo];
 });
 return novoConteudo;
});

console.log(arrays);
```